# Any good source explaining multiprocessor synchronization techniques and their implementation

Tags: reference-request, operating-systems, synchronization

I need to study how synchronization is done in a multiprocessor operating system, but I am unable to find a good source. I have read about it in the book "Modern Operating System" by Tanenbaum, but I need to study the actual implementation in more detail.
Any good book/paper or online blog post will do.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by _synchronization_?

Comment: I meant synchronization in operating systems i.e. thread and process synchronization. In other words the solution to the critical section problem.

Comment: Conceptually, I do not see any difference between uni-processor and multi-processor environments: access to the critical section should be protected by a mutex. Are you looking for references describing how this is actually implemented in a multi-processor environment?

Comment: Yes, I am looking for references.

Comment: What not good resources have you seen? Why these were not good? To learn any concept, you have to read multiple resources and selected resource, the best for me, may not be good for you, and vice versa, so it is crucial to narrow down scope and expectations, to make your question answerable.

Comment: Dude, I have searched through two most respectable books on operating systems i.e. Tanenbaum's and Silbershatz's. I could not find enough information in them regarding actual implementation. Similarly, on the internet I could not find it in detail.  So, if you are aware of any book/paper regarding the topic that I could use, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Google for Posix mutex.